# When do mobs turn grey?

Tags: everquest-2

At level 63, level 56 mobs are still green. When will they turn grey? I am also interested in the general formula for when mobs turn grey.

Comment: level 52 mobs are grey, level 53 mobs are green, at 63.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the formula is 11 levels. At 10 they are still green.

HTH